# Elasticsearch autosuggest

Tags: elasticsearch, autosuggest

a newbie to ES needs helping hands for the Suggester....
I made a simple index with some titles like "Manufacturer product name mpn":

My current Mapping:

```
'suggest'=> [
'=> 'completion'
'=> 'simple'
' => false
]
```

my current Query:

```
'body' => [
'suggest' => [
'text' => $this->query
, 'completion' => [
'field' => 'suggest'
]]]
```

Now if I try to Suggest it works, but results are very ugly....
Perhaps somebody can help me to find the right settings:

e.g. a title is: "Xoar Electric Beechwood Precision"

Now i want this results for Queries:

```
"X" => "Xoar"
"Yoar E" => "Xoar", "Xoar Electric"
"El" => "Electric"
"Elektric " => "Electric", "Electric Beechwood"
```

At the moment it only returns the full title if I type "X...."

Is this possible? 
And if yes, how can i try to get this results?

THANKS in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You need to change default tokenizer and analyzer to fetch related documents from elasticsearch.

Check below links for more details which talks about how to handle human language and typo corrections,

[Human Languages with elasticsearch](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/languages.html)

[Fuzzy matching with elasticsearch](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/fuzzy-matching.html%20Fuzzy-matching)

Answer (score 0):

You should use `ngrams` approach i.e. tokenize your words by splitting them with space character or what suits your use case the most. Then index each token with the suggest analyzer.

For ex:

Split *"Xoar Electric Beechwood Precision"* like this

- "Xoar Electric Beechwood Precision"
- "Electric Beechwood Precision"
- "Beechwood Precision"
- "Precision"

And then use the `prefix` query. For auto-correcting, you may use `fuzziness` parameter.

Hope this helps.